# Convert SQL to Doctrine 2 Query Builder or DQL by using NOT IN?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

How would I convert the SQL bellow to Doctrine 2 Query Builder or DQL?

```
SELECT tags.* 
FROM tags 
WHERE tags.id NOT IN (
                     SELECT tag_id AS totalTags 
                     FROM human_resource_tags 
                     WHERE human_resource_id=1)
```

Tag entity is as follows:

[Tag entity](http://pastebin.com/nL499ee1)

HumanResource entity is as follows:

[HumanResource entity](http://pastebin.com/gPccQ6pi)

Basically what I want to do is to select all Tag entities for one HumanResource entity that that HumanResource entity does not have already.

I am really struggling here so any help is appreciated.

I am using Doctrine version 2.4.2.

==========================================================================

All hail to FuzzyTree for pointers :)

I have slightly modified it and it works like a charm :)
So this will get you all Tag entities for particular HumanResource entity that are not added to 
HumanResource entity yet :)

SO THIS IS SOLUTION:

```
$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
      ->where('t.name LIKE :name')
      ->andWhere('NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT h
                    FROM HRAPIBundle:HumanResource h 
                    WHERE h.id = ' . $humanResource->getId() .
                    'AND h MEMBER of t.human_resources
                )')
      ->setParameter('name', "%".$query."%")
      ->getQuery();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `NOT EXISTS` and `MEMBER OF`

```
$qb->select("t")
    ->from('HardCoreMore\HRAPIBundle\Entity\Tag', 't')
    ->where('NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM HardCoreMore\HRAPIBundle\Entity\HumanResource h 
        WHERE h.id = 1 
        AND h MEMBER of t.human_resources
      )');
```

Comment: Thanks a million man. This was one of those moments when I did not have a chance without some help from internet. :) Cheeers :)

Answer (score 0):

Select your `$hmEntity`that you don't want then use the follow code:

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 $result= $em->getRepository('HRAPIBundle:Tag')->findByHumanResource(!$hmEntity);
```

Comment: I get error "Entity 'HardCoreMore\HRAPIBundle\Entity\Tag' has no field 'humanResource'. You can therefore not call 'findByHumanResource' on the entities' repository"

Comment: You should add this on controller.

Comment: I do not understand. What should I add on controller?

Comment: `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$hmEntity = $em->getRepository('HRAPIBundle:HumanResource')->find($id);
 $result= $em->getRepository('HRAPIBundle:Tag')->findByHumanResource($hmEntity)`




This code will find all Tags where HumanResource is equals `$hmEntity`(this should be a instace of HumanResource), you just need do this on controller that call a twig that render what you want and do the opposite.

Comment: But I did call it on controller and I get the error that entity Tag does not have field 'humanResource' and that I can not call findByHumanResource method.