# Doctrine, select books with no comments

Tags: php, sql, doctrine

I have got for say a table book and a table comment
I want to retrieve the book who has no comment.
How should i do that with doctrine

In SQL I would do

`SELECT * FROM books WHERE books.id NOT IN ( SELECT book_id FROM comments )`

But do you have the solution with doctrine, it seems not to be so simple.

Comment: have you tried your solution?

Comment: NO, it doesn't seem to solve the problem, what is it ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you meant by doctrine solution

Comment: TABLE books ( title VARCHAR 255, id: INTEGER ) TABLE comments ( book_id: INTEGER )

Comment: I mean implement this with doctrine ORM.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938497/convert-sql-to-doctrine-2-query-builder-or-dql-by-using-not-in

Comment: No infact, that is not what I want, the answers table may have entries at some points. I want the books that are not linked to answers.

Comment: I think what you need it's this. [subqueries doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#subqueries)